# Access form Synchronize horizontal bar on subforms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that contains two subforms.  I'm trying to sync the horizontal bar so when the user moves the bar to the left or right on either subform they both move at the same time.

Comment: This is not possible using present events and methods. Perhaps with some extensive API coding, but even that may turn out fruitless.

Comment: You could try this setup: Main form --- container subform, which only contains the two subforms, and has horizontal scrollbar = True --- sub-subforms, with horizontal scrollbar = False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, by nesting the two subforms (A and B) in another subform (C).

Within form C, subforms A and B are sized to their full widths, so they won't have horizontal scrollbars.

Within the main form, subform C is sized to fit the width of the main form.

When the main form is open, subform C's horizontal scrollbar will scroll subforms A and B in unison.

(This is what Andre suggested, but worded differently!)